# How to select rows where a condition is met in R?

Tags: r, select, conditional-statements, subset

I'm quite new to R and working on conditions in R language.
I have a dataframe looking like this :

```
ID   nb
11    1
11    2
11    3
24    1
24    2
32    1
41    1
41    2
```

And I want to subset rows where nb = max(nb) for each different ID, and so get this new dataframe :

```
ID   nb
11    3
24    2
32    1
41    2
```

If possible is there a way to do this without a loop ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `tidyverse` family of functions, which lets you do this very easily! They're very useful functions to be familiar with. (In particular, if you know the core `dplyr` functions, you can do most everything you'll need to do in R.)

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(nb == max(nb)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` with `max` and `merge`:

```
merge(x, aggregate(nb~ID, x, max))
#  ID nb
#1 11  3
#2 24  2
#3 32  1
#4 41  2
```